# Display images in serverside datatable

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have server-side datatable in which I'm trying to show images in `showimage` column.
I tried to change code for rendering column using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152698/displaying-image-on-datatable) which is as below but no images are displayed in table:

Server_processing.php:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'office',     'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 
        'db' => 'showimage',
        'dt' => 4,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '<img src="$d" style="height:50px;width:50px;"/>';
        }       
        ),  
    array(
        'db'        => 'salary',
        'dt'        => 6,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '$'.number_format($d);
        }
    )
);
```

With above code, in `src` image path is not displayed as a result image is not displayed.
It is showing when go thru source code as `src="$d"`

Mysql database: [Mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZThU.jpg)
I have placed images at both places where .html resides and in `images` folder.

Comment: @Aniket Sahrawat, Thanks, I am new to all this, can you please help me.

Comment: I am not getting you, here is the datatable i am using: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace below line:

```
return "<img class='zoom' src='$d' style='height:50px;width:50px;align:middle;'/>";
```

Comment: Interesting. The single quote vs double quote really did make a difference. Good to know! Thanks.