# Show an image in a "Jquery Datatable Plugin" cell using "columns.render" callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to display an image in a cell using the suggested answer from this post: [Displaying image on Datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152698/displaying-image-on-datatable).

However, the first parameter of the callback (data) should receive the string with the url pointing to the image, but it is always **undefined**.

This is how I initialize the datatable (columnDefs contains the callback I was talking about):

```
$().ready(function () {
    var opt = {
        columnDefs: [{
                "targets": 2,
                "data": 'teamLogo',
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<img src="' + data + '" alt="' + data + '"height="16" width="16"/>';
                }
            }],
        info: false,
        order: [[0, 'asc']],
        paging: false,
        responsive: true,
        searching: false
    };
    $('#dataTable').DataTable(opt);
});
```

After an ajax call, I update data into the table, drawing it back again:

```
$('#cmbSeasons').change(function () {
    var leagueId = parseInt($('#cmbLeagues').val().toString());
    var seasonYear = parseInt($('#cmbSeasons').val().toString());
    var settings = {
        url: '/Standing/Read/Standings',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { leagueId: leagueId, seasonYear: seasonYear },
        success: function (data) {
            var t = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
            t.clear();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                t.row.add([
                    data[i].rank,
                    data[i].teamName,
                    data[i].teamLogo,
                    data[i].points,
                    data[i].allPlayed,
                    data[i].allWin,
                    data[i].allDraw,
                    data[i].allLose,
                    data[i].allGoalsFor,
                    data[i].allGoalsAgainst,
                    data[i].homePlayed,
                    data[i].homeWin,
                    data[i].homeDraw,
                    data[i].homeLose,
                    data[i].homeGoalsFor,
                    data[i].homeGoalsAgainst,
                    data[i].awayPlayed,
                    data[i].awayWin,
                    data[i].awayDraw,
                    data[i].awayLose,
                    data[i].awayGoalsFor,
                    data[i].awayGoalsAgainst
                ]);
            }
            t.draw();
        },
        error: function (result) { alert('error ' + result.status + ': ' + result.responseText); }
    };
    $.ajax(settings);
});
```

The third column (data[i].teamLogo) contains the correct url I want to use as src for the image (I'm sure about it because I used the developer console to check the correctness of the string).

This is html Markup:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="text-center">
    <thead class="text-capitalize">
        <tr>
            <th class="all">Rank</th>
            <th class="all">Team</th>
            <th class="all">Logo</th>
            <th class="all">Pts</th>
            <th class="all">Pl</th>
            <th class="all">W</th>
            <th class="all">D</th>
            <th class="all">L</th>
            <th class="all">GF</th>
            <th class="all">GA</th>
            <th class="all">HPl</th>
            <th class="all">HW</th>
            <th class="all">HD</th>
            <th class="all">HL</th>
            <th class="all">HGF</th>
            <th class="all">HGA</th>
            <th class="all">APl</th>
            <th class="all">AW</th>
            <th class="all">AD</th>
            <th class="all">AL</th>
            <th class="all">AGF</th>
            <th class="all">AGA</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there anything wrong with the callback I wrote? Should be "data" parameter populated with a different string, instead of 'teamLogo'?

I'm using the latest version of datatables (1.10.20) and Jquery (3.5.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the definition of the options this way:

```
$().ready(function () {
    let opt: DataTables.Settings = {
        columns: [
            { "data": "rank" },
            { "data": "teamName" },
            { "data": "teamLogo" },
            { "data": "points" },
            { "data": "allPlayed" },
            { "data": "allWin" },
            { "data": "allDraw" },
            { "data": "allLose" },
            { "data": "allGoalsFor" },
            { "data": "allGoalsAgainst" },
            { "data": "homePlayed" },
            { "data": "homeWin" },
            { "data": "homeDraw" },
            { "data": "homeLose" },
            { "data": "homeGoalsFor" },
            { "data": "homeGoalsAgainst" },
            { "data": "awayPlayed" },
            { "data": "awayWin" },
            { "data": "awayDraw" },
            { "data": "awayLose" },
            { "data": "awayGoalsFor" },
            { "data": "awayGoalsAgainst" }
        ],
        columnDefs:
            [{
                "targets": 2,
                "data": 'teamLogo',
                "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<img src="' + data + '" alt="' + data + '"height="16" width="16"/>';
                }
            }],
        info: false,
        order: [[0, 'asc']],
        paging: false,
        responsive: true,
        searching: false
    }
    $('#dataTable').DataTable(opt);
});
```

and simplifying the for loop like this:

```
t.rows.add( data ).draw();
```

did the trick!

It seemes that I had to define the data columns for the callback to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
return '<img src="' + data + '" alt="' + data + '"height="16" width="16"/>';
```

use an Img object to return instead
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to tell me, but anyway I think that if we don't get the correct url from the callback we will not be able to use neither solution.